# Output segment_x via template HTML

Tags: templates, segments

Using EE 2.5.5, I wish to output a segment_x (segment_2, which aligns with our department names) so that I may class by department; i.e.,

```
<article class="main {segment_2}">
    <more html goes here>
```

would become

```
<article class="main lead-pipes">
    <more html goes here>
```

However, I can not add {segment_2} to HTML portions of the 
template, nothing outputs.

How to do so?

Comment: It should be as simple as `{segment_2}` with nothing else you need to do. Have you checked what is being output in the browser dev tools?

Comment: You are correct Ian. There's several if/thens in the layout, I was updating the wrong block. Make it an answer I'll happily send you some points.

Comment: Sure thing. I've added it as an answer below. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as `{segment_2}` with nothing else you need to do. Have you checked what is being output in the browser dev tools?